# Why it still shows me results

Tags: c#

In this part, if my waist is less than 60 and height greater than 120, the result box will be shown. But when waist is greater than 60 and height less than 120 the result won't be shown. How to block the first situation happens that the result should be shown.

```
            if (this.Male.Checked) {
            if (waist < 60) {
                MessageBox.Show("Your waist is too low to calculate, please enter a higer numer");
            }

            if (height < 120) {
                MessageBox.Show("Your height is too low to calculate, please enter a higer numer");
            }
            else{

                if (ratio < Male_Risk) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your ratio is: " + ratio + "\n" + "your raito is at low risk, please be careful");

                } 
                else {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your ratio is: " + ratio + "\n" + "Warning : your raito is at high risk, please save yourself!");

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Since there is no `else` statement tying the two if-statements together they should work independently. Please explain more and try to debug your application.

Comment: Use else if instead of twice if, now they are seperate  conditions, so the if (height <120) should be else if (height <120)

Comment: But once my two values both are lower than limited, it only show one message that waist is low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements for checking the waist and height are not linked together. So if your patient has a waist greater than 60 but is his height is less than 120, then you result won't be shown because the second if statement you had is not linked with the if statement above. That means the else part will only be shown if height ist greater than 120.

Just change `if(height < 120)` to `else if(height < 120)`

Like this:

```
if (this.Male.Checked) 
{
    if (waist < 60) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your waist is too low to calculate, please enter a higer numer");
    }

    else if (height < 120) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your height is too low to calculate, please enter a higer numer");
    }
    else 
    {
        if (ratio < Male_Risk) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your ratio is: " + ratio + "\n" + "your raito is at low risk, please be careful");
        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your ratio is: " + ratio + "\n" + "Warning : your raito is at high risk, please save yourself!");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to show both `MessageBox`'s, you need to put the waist and height check in a separated `if` like this:

```
if(waist < 60 || height < 120) 
{
    if (waist < 60) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your waist is too low to calculate, please enter a higer numer");
    }
    if (height < 120) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your height is too low to calculate, please enter a higer numer");
    }
}
else 
{
     // Put your ratio results here...
}
```

Comment: what if both values are lower the limited, it only show one message box

Comment: Yes of course. Because now they are linked together. If you want to show both message boxes wait for my answer to update